# position: absolute stopping window.addEventListener firing in vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have my `vue` app which I am using `position: absolute` in my 'ContentBody' so that my `vertical scroll` is not displayed in my 'Header/Footer' but the issue I'm having now is that due to using this, it's stopping all my `window.addEventListener('scroll'` from firing.

Is there another way?

as soon as I remove my `position: absolute` it works perfectly.

```
created() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.reportInfoDiv);
    console.log('111')
},

reportInfoDiv() {
    console.log('reportInfoDiv') // NEVER HITS THIS
    const currentScrollPosition = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;

    if (currentScrollPosition < 78) {
        this.showReportInfo = false;
    } else {
        this.showReportInfo = true;
    }
},
```

I have also tried using `@scroll="test"` and `:scroll="test"` but still never seems to fire

Comment: I'm not sure what your CSS looks like, but from a CSS perspective, absolute positioning and scrolling don't always play well together. Are you sure that `position: fixed` or `static` wouldn't work?

Comment: @MitchLillie Tried `fixed` and still doesn't fire at all. Soon as I remove it it does and `static` no good for me